# Ensuring window focus on OpenGL App

Tags: winapi, opengl, focus

I have three executables compiled from Visual C++ using OpenGL libraries. Though nothing is different between them in how the window is created, one of them automatically has focus when I run it and the other two require the user to click on the window before they are given focus.

I'm building a WIN32 application as a menu to run the different .exe files, and in here I'm using all the usual suggestions to attempt to focus the windows (SetFocus(hWnd) SetActiveWindow(hWnd)), but to no avail.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is actually `SetForegroundWindow (...)`, because in addition to setting the active window, this will bring your application into the foreground.

`SetActiveWindow (hWnd)` will only accomplish what you want if your application is in the foreground, it is useful if you have a multi-document application and want to switch between windows.

Here is a relevant selection of code that I use in my Win32 window management system when initializing / resizing a rendercontext:

```
ShowWindow          (hWndRender, SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow (hWndRender);
SetFocus            (hWndRender);
```